# NoClassDefFoundError with the EclEmma code coverage tool

Tags: android, testing, code-coverage, android-testing, eclemma

I tried to use the EclEmma code coverage tool to check coverage of test cases, but got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
```

How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the fact on [eclEmma homepage](http://www.eclemma.org/devdoc/eclemma20.html) that eclEmma is not supported in Java 7 because it fails with java7 bytecode:( if you go back to Java6 you can use it!

Comment: Will conversion from java 7 to 6 affect to android project?

Comment: @Justink  If you don't use the java7 features you can convert your project easily.

Comment: Hey, I have checked on my project properties, "java compiler version is 1.6" only. Still I am getting error of class not found. I have place image of my project properties along the main question.

Comment: @Justink Could you tell me what you can read in the middle of eclipse? I'm interested in the line starts with <terminated> like in your first screeshot.

Comment: I have uploaded a zoom out version of that image. Please let me know if you need any more infor.

Comment: @Justink I'm not a java version expert but I think you should install JDK1.6 too to be able to use it. I'm not sure. But your question is answered, you should go back to java6 to use eclEmma. That's all I can help you.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, but I am sure I am not using Java 1.7. The jre I use is 1.6.0.33, yet I still get this problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this Justin? I'm having the same issue and it's killing me.